# Не заполняет массив ранд. числами с++ и по этому не работает метод show

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
 template <class ST = int, int len = 10> class Tset
    {
    private:
        ST *Set;
        ST len;
    public:
        Tset()
        {
            register int i;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                Set[i] = 0+rand()%10;
            }
        }
    void show()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                cout <<Set[i] << endl;
            }
        }
```

Comment: потому что массива у вас нет, а есть неинициализированный указатель. Не путайте указатель с массивом, это разные понятия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А выделить в конструкторе память? Что-то типа

```
Tset():Set(new int[len])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        Set[i] = 0+rand()%10;
    }
}
```

И забывайте о ключевом слове `register` - оно ни к чему.

Comment: и написать копирование  и деструктор

Comment: А лучше stl контейнер использовать и не мучаться.

Comment: Ну или, если размер передаётся в параметре шаблона, сделать статический массив.

Comment: Даже если это и скомпилируется каким-то чудом (в контексте исходного кода), разумно ожидать, что скорее всего `len` будет ссылаться на поле класса (а не на шаблонный параметр). А поле класса содержит мусор.

Answer (score 2):

Не понятно, о каком "не работает метод show" вы ведете речь. Язык С++ запрещает переиспользование (переобъявление) имен шаблонных параметров в их области видимости. Поэтому вот это

```
template <class ST = int, int len = 10> class Tset
{
private:
    ST *Set;
    ST len;  // <-- ERROR: имя `len` уже занято
```

уже не компилируемо в принципе. Не ясно также почему поле `len` вдруг объявлено с типом `ST`.

В чем смысл шаблонного параметра `len`? Если вы хотели создать массив, чей размер является константой времени компиляции, то

```
template <class ST = int, int len = 10> class Tset
{
private:
    ST Set[len];
```

и никакого поля `len` в классе не нужно.

Если же вы хотели создать массив переменного размера, то почему тогда `len` сделано параметром шаблона???

Comment: Верно подмечено, а я даже не заметил(думаю и  Harry тоже)...